# a functions for positive integers

Tags: functions

For a modeling, i need a descending function. for example i need something like this:

```
input  output
  1      1 
  2      2
     ...
  6      6
  7      6 
  8      6 
  9      7
     ...
  100    18
     ...
```

(the output numbers are almost thing that i need)(all inputs are int)
What is your suggestions?

Comment: Your question is pretty generic. A function where the output scales slower than the output would be something like output = (m)(input) where $0 < m < 1$. Round the output in some direction. Are you looking for something non-linear that would fit your example exactly?

Comment: it's work linear! i want a function like logarithmic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a function that approximates well the output values, does this image remind you of a particular function?[image]
With a bit of homemade *interpolation* you can see a sketch of the logarithmic function:
[image]
I think a good approximation is given by the function $$y=\frac{\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2.42)}\right)^2}{x^{0.11}} + 1.5=\frac{\log^2_{2.42}(x)}{x^{\frac{11}{100}}}+\frac{3}{2}$$
[image]

Comment: Do you can estimate a function with this numbers?

Comment: What software did you use for this drawing?

Comment: simply *Microsoft Excel* $\to$ *Graph plotting*

Comment: I've edited the answer...check it out! ;)

Comment: then I used old friend *GeoGebra*...http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/